# Typescript | Typescript is missing 27 Props, when extending formikProps on IProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-props, formik

I am using Formik with TypeScript, and I want to use a very simple form component in TS, within another component from which I take the `defaultValues` and the `validationSchemas`.

The tricky part is how to access only the desired formikProps, and not get the following error:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<IProps>': values, errors, touched, isValidating, and 25 more.ts(2740)
(alias) class PasswordFields
import PasswordFields
```

Here is the code for the component:

```
interface IProps extends FormikProps<IValues> {
  username?: string;
  email?: string;
}

interface IValues {
  username?: string;
  email?: string;
}
```

And in the main component I am calling it like that:

```
render(): ReactNode {
    const { mode } = this.props;
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={this.getInitialValues()}
        validationSchema={this.getValidationSchemas()}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        render={({ isSubmitting, status }) =>
          (
            <Form>
              {mode === ActionMode.EDIT_INFO && (
                <Fragment>
                  <InfoFields /> // I am getting the error here..
                  <GroupSelectField />
                </Fragment>
              )}
              <Button
                className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-5"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                loading={isSubmitting}
                type="submit"
              >
                {mode === ActionMode.EDIT_INFO && <span>UPDATE INFO</span>}
              </Button>
            </Form>
          ) as ReactNode
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

I am kind of stack on this. Could you tell me how to access only the formikProps that I want, so TS, doesn't complain.?? And I also have another problem. How to pass the props from the component to the formik forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696213/react-how-to-pass-formikprops-one-component-up) that has the same issue, `InfoFields` is expecting props that you are not passing in:

```
<Formik
    render={formikProps => (
        <Form>
            // Other Code.

            <InfoFields {...formikProps} />

            // Other Code.
        </Form>
    )}
/>
```

> Could you tell me how to access only the formikProps that I want, so TS, doesn't complain

Instead of the above you can select the props you actually want from `FormikProps` and pass them into `InfoFields`. For example something like this:

```
const InfoFields = ({ errors, touched }: Pick<FormikProps<IValues>, 'errors' | 'touched'>) => (
    <div>
        // Whatever.
    </div>
);
```

... and rendered in the parent component with this:

```
<Formik
    render={({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form>
            // Other Code.

            <InfoFields errors={errors} touched={touched} />

            // Other Code.
        </Form>
    )}
/>
```

Comment: This is actually really helpful. Thank you. Ended up making the component in `.jsx` instead. But with that I can convert them to `.tsx` . Thank you very much.